# Equilibria of two equations - and their correspondence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider a reaction-diffusion system
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{(1)}
u_t=Du_{xx}+F(u)\in\mathbb{R}^N.
\end{equation}
Making the modulated travelling wave ansatz 
\begin{equation}
u=u(\xi,\tau)\text{ with }\xi=x-ct\text{ and }\tau=\omega t, 
\end{equation}
I get the so-called modulated travelling wave equation
\begin{equation}
u_{\xi\xi}=D^{-1}(-cu_{\xi}+\omega u_{\tau}-F(u))
\end{equation}
which as a first-order system in the spatial variable $\xi$ can be written as
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{(2)}
&u_{\xi}=v\\
&v_{\xi}=D^{-1}(-cv+\omega u_{\tau}-F(u)).
\end{align}

Regard system $\eqref{(2)}$ as a dynamical system with an underlying rotational symmetry acting through the temporal shift
\begin{equation}
v(\xi,\tau)\mapsto \Gamma(\varphi)(v)=v(\xi,\tau+\varphi), \varphi\in S^1.
\end{equation}

Next, two statements are made which I think I do not fully understand.

> > **(a)** Spatially homogeneous equilibria of equation $\eqref{(1)}$ correspond to equilibria of the system $\eqref{(2)}$ contained in the fixed point space $\text{Fix}(S^1)$.
> >
> > **(b)** Spatially periodic, temporally steady solutions of equation $\eqref{(1)}$ correspond to periodic orbits, or, more precisely, relative equilibria of system $\eqref{(2)}$ with respect to the $S^1$-symmetry:
> >     $$
> > v(\xi,\tau)=v_{*}(x)=v_{*}\left(\xi+\frac{c}{\omega}\tau\right).
> > $$

---

**My explanations**:

I am not sure if they make sense! Anyway, I post them here in order to get some feedback or help.

### **(a)**:

For simplicity, let $D=1$. Let $\tilde{u}=\tilde{u}(x,t)$ be a spatially homogeneous equilibrium of equation $\eqref{(1)}$: 
$$
\tilde{u}_t=D\underbrace{\tilde{u}_{xx}}_{=0}+F(\tilde{u})=0\implies F(\tilde{u})=0. 
$$
For the system $\eqref{(2)}$,
\begin{align}
&u_{\xi}=v\\
&v_{\xi}=-cv+\omega u_{\tau}-F(u),
\end{align}
the solution $(\tilde{u},\tilde{u}_{\xi})(\xi,\tau)$ is an equilibrium if $v=\tilde{u}_{\xi}=0$ (since then the first equation is zero) and $\tilde{u}_{\tau}=0$ (since then the second equation is zero).

But, as far as I see,
$$
\tilde{u}_{\xi}=0=\tilde{u}_{\tau}\implies \tilde{u}(\xi,\tau)\in\text{Fix}(S^1)
$$
since otherwise (i.e. if $\Gamma(\tilde{u}(\xi,\tau))=\tilde{u}(\xi,\tau+\varphi)$ for some $\varphi\in S^1$), $\tilde{u}_{\tau}\neq 0$.

### **(b)**:

Again, let $D=1$ for simplicity. Let $\tilde{u}=\tilde{u}(x,t)$ be a spatially periodic, temporally steady solution of equation $\eqref{(1)}$.

Then 
$$
u(\xi,\tau)=(\tilde{u},v=\tilde{u}_{\xi})(\xi,\tau)=\left(\tilde{u}\left(\xi+\frac{c}{\omega}\tau\right),v\left(\xi+\frac{c}{\omega}\tau\right)\right)=(\tilde{u}(x),v(x))
$$
is a solution of the system $\eqref{(2)}$ if the spatial periodicity of $\tilde{u}$ is $\tilde{u}(x)=\tilde{u}(x+L)$ with $L=\frac{2\pi}{k}, k=\frac{\omega}{c}$.

In particular,
$$
\tilde{u}(x)=\tilde{u}\left(\xi+\frac{c}{\omega}\tau\right)
$$
is a travelling wave solution in the coordinates $(\xi,\tau)$ and hence a wave train since $\tilde{u}(x)$ is spatially periodic by assumption. Hence, in the phase space, $\tilde{u}(x)$ is a periodic orbit.

Moreover, as a travelling wave in the coordinates $(x=\xi+\frac{c}{\omega}\tau,\tau)$, the solution $\tilde{u}(x)$ does not depend on the second coordinate $\tau$ and hence the translation map $\Gamma$ has no influence on the solution $\tilde{u}(x)$.

In other words: With respect to the $S^1$-symmetry, acting through $\Gamma$ on the second coordinate $\tau$, $\tilde{u}$ is an equilibrium since nothing happens with $\tilde{u}$ if the symmetry is acting.